# Max file size/time for a video to autoplay

Tags: video, autoplay

What's the max file size and/or max seconds a html5 video limit in order for a video to auto play on a handheld device?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any size restriction set in the specification, but the autoplay attribute is ignored by mobile devices to prevent unnecessary data usage. Video's will only be played when the user initiates it.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of video should be 20 seconds